# Uncaught Invariant Violation: Target container is not a DOM element. I added in view file too

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel

I have `React` code which contains a basic button. I want to show it in `laravel's` blade file. So I did the following:

**File: dashboard.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class Dashboard extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <button type = "button" onClick = {this.SigninWithGoogle}>Sigin With google</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default Dashboard;

if (document.getElementById('Dashboard')) {
    ReactDOM.render(<Dashboard />, document.getElementById('Dashboard'));
}
```

**and my blade file:**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Register') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">

                        <div class = "Register" id = "Dashboard">
                        </div>
                        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/App.js"></script>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

I am able to view the button in view page, but I'm getting following error in the console.

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: Target container is not a DOM element.

Please can someone tell me what the issue is with this code?

Comment: Move the script import to `layouts/app.blade.php` at the bottom of the body tag

Comment: I tried . But I can able to view the `button` from js file. But still getting error at console.